# MEANJS create modules using YO

Tags: crud, meanjs, yo

I downloaded MeanJs project from Github and used Yo generator to create new CRUD module by using next command:

**yo meanjs:crud-module xxxx**

But it looks like the module been created in different location, not the same location where other modules are located... and the module menu wasn't visible at top menu, however I been asked to give a location...

How to create a new module if I'm not using YO MeanJs generator?
Please take a look on screenshot.

[Project tree structure](http://pasteboard.co/oGBAGPF.png)

Folder **/MODULE** created by default from GIT repository, but after running g YO generator creates new folder **/APP** and new module content was added to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you use meanjs 0.4.0 or the latest 0.4.1 you should download the github repository and add the modules you want by yourself. Do not use yo to make modules because the generator is currently broken for 0.4.0 and 0.4.1 versions.

As explained in meanjs official [website](http://meanjs.org/generator.html):

> The generator is for the 0.3.x stable release! The generator for the
>   latest master/0.4.0 release is under development. See the github repo
>   for more information about the 0.4.0 generator

Comment: I'm using stable 0.3 version and following steps described in main website documentation.